# Lorenz condition and uncoupling pde - general name for techniques of pde uncoupling

Tags: partial-differential-equations, electromagnetism

I'm reading Jackson's Electrodynamics chapter 6.2.

It is possible to reduce Maxwell's equations to

$\nabla^2 \phi + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\nabla \cdot A) = - \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$  (6.10)

$\nabla^2 A - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial t^2} - \nabla( \nabla \cdot A + \frac{1}{c^2}  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t }) = - \mu_0 J$  (6.11)

By satisfying Lorenz condition

One can uncouple into

$\nabla^2 \phi - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} = \frac{- \rho}{\epsilon_0}$

$\nabla^2 A - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial t^2} = - \mu_0 J$

I have not seen this kind of thing outside of the context of electromagnetism.  Is there a more general name for this kind of thing in mathematics for uncoupling pde?

Comment: Perhaps it is "Potential Theory" that categorizes "this kind of thing."

Comment: Thank you. Looking this up now.